# How to retrieve US visa appointment payment receipt

Tags: visas, us-visa-waiver-program, h1b-visas, us-visa

I was waiting for scheduling H1B in person interview for myself and dependents (wife and child) so I paid for 3 of us in cgi portal and got the payment receipt number auto populated.

Since I was eligible for drop box I removed them from the dependent list and scheduled the drop box appointment for me.

But now I need to schedule H4 dependent appointment for my wife and child.  Where can I find the payment receipt number of my wife and child?  I didn’t save it anywhere as it was auto populating.  Is there any way to retrieve it?

Answer (score 1):

It happen to me, after paying fees, while coming back from bank, I lost my receipt on way. (May be it left on bank desk or fall from my pocket while driving my motorcycle).

If you know where did you paid, like bank or something, then they can provide that. I did that. Went to the bank, and give them date on which I paid the fees. They gave me another copy for the receipt.